# Solving $(-1)^{n+1}n\sin(\omega x)-\sin(\omega y)=0$, $(-1)^{n+1}nx\cos(\omega x)-y\cos(\omega y)=0$, $y-nx=\frac{z}{c}$ for given $n$?

Tags: trigonometry

I try to solve the following problem, which consists of 3 equations and 3 unknowns.
\begin{align}
(-1)^{n+1}n\sin(\omega x)-\sin(\omega y) &=0 \tag1\\
(-1)^{n+1}nx\cos(\omega x)-y\cos(\omega y) &=0 \tag2\\
y - nx &= \frac{z}{c} \tag3
\end{align}
Suppose $\omega$ and $c$ are known variables. $n$ is an integer and $n\geq 2$. Eq. $(2)$ is the derivative with respect to $\omega$ of Eq. $(1)$. I try to solve for the variable $x$, $y$ and $z$. I tried to take $y = \frac{z}{c} + nx$ and plug it into Eq. $(1)$ and Eq. $(2)$, which gives
\begin{align}
(-1)^{n+1}n\sin(\omega x)-\sin\left(\omega \left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\right) &=0 \tag4\\
(-1)^{n+1}nx\cos(\omega x)-\left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\cos\left(\omega \left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\right) &=0 \tag5\\
\end{align}
This can be written as
\begin{align}
(-1)^{n+1}n\sin(\omega x) &= \sin\left(\omega \left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\right) \tag6\\
(-1)^{n+1}nx\cos(\omega x) &= \left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\cos\left(\omega \left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\right)\tag7\\
\end{align}
Here I reached a point where I am left with 2 equations and just 2 unknowns, considering we know $n$. So I tried dividing Eq. $(6)$ by Eq. $(7)$ and got
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x}\tan(\omega x) = \frac{\tan\left(\frac{z}{c}+nx\right)}{\frac{z}{c}+nx}
\end{align}
and I feel that I am stuck. Setting $n=2$ won't help me to express $x$ in terms of $z$ or vice versa. So I tried to illustrate the problem and created vectors for $x$ and $z$ by using MATLAB and plotted the values of
\begin{align}
f_1(x,z) = (-1)^{n+1}n\sin(\omega x)-\sin\left(\omega \left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\right)\\
f_2(x,z) = (-1)^{n+1}nx\cos(\omega x)-\left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\cos\left(\omega \left(\frac{z}{c} + nx\right)\right)
\end{align}
which is Eq. $(4)$ and Eq. $(5)$, when $f_1=f_2=0$. Over the $x$ and $z$ space I receive [surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF3NP.png) (I set $\omega=2\pi$, $c=480$ and $n=2,3...$), which show me the solution when they cut trough the zero surface. I attached the plot to the question, where the green surface is $f_1$, the blue surface is $f_2$ and the red surface is marking the zero surface. I highlighted the points which are solving for this set of equation. Is there a way for a closed form solution, given I set $n=2,3...$? I am glad for any hint of the community, thank you for your time.